# How to create a table using 'Class A' in SQLite and have the properties of 'Class B' as columns?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have these classes:

```
public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [????]
    public Address Address{ get; set; }
}

public class Address{
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Street{get; set;}
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string City{get; set;}
}
```

And I wanted to create a Person Table with Street and City as columns in the table.

Is this possible using SQLite?

Comment: create 2 tables and use a foreign key constraint

Comment: What framework do you use to connect your program to SQLite?